# How to populate Google Maps API InfoWindow with content from JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have searched the forum (endlessly) trying everything I found but nothing works. I have the following code. I want to be able to click on one of the markers and have an InfoWindow popup with unique content derived from the corresponding JSON so that the window has the Location, Date-Time, and Details and I can target them with different html/css. Nothing works. Any help?

HTML

```
<head>
<title>Data Layer: Simple</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="mymap"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=REDACTED&callback=initMap">
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";

  #mymap {
        height: 100%;
      }

 html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
  var ufomap;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initMap() {
        ufomap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mymap'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: {lat:37.0902,lng:-95.7129}
        });

        ufomap.data.loadGeoJson('json.geojson');

        }
```

JSON

```
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{
            "Location":"Greensburg, PA",
            "Date-Time":"1969-01-01T10:00:00",
            "Shape”:”Circle”,
            "Details":"Possible contact with Visitor as a child When I was 2 to 4 years old",
            "Latitude":"40.33569572",
            "Longitude":"-79.55026848"
         },
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -79.550268,
               40.335696
            ]
         }
      },
{
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{
            "Location”:”Smithtown, PA",
            "Date-Time":"1979-01-01T10:00:00",
            "Shape”:”Square”,
            "Details”:”Bright lights flashing“,
            "Latitude":"44.33569572",
            "Longitude":"-78.55026848"
         },
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -78.550268,
               44.335696
            ]
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your GeoJSON is not valid (there are errors reported in the JavaScript console). Run it through [geojsonlint.com](http://geojsonlint.com/) and fix any errors (or fix the errors reported in the JavaScript console). What you posted fixed:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "Location": "Greensburg, PA",
        "Date-Time": "1969-01-01T10:00:00",
        "Shape": "Circle",
        "Details": "Possible contact with Visitor as a child When I was 2 to 4 years old",
        "Latitude": "40.33569572",
        "Longitude": "-79.55026848"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -79.550268,
          40.335696
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "Location": "Smithtown, PA",
        "Date-Time": "1979-01-01T10:00:00",
        "Shape": "Square",
        "Details": "Bright lights flashing",
        "Latitude": "44.33569572",
        "Longitude": "-78.55026848"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -78.550268,
          44.335696
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

2. If I make if valid, and use the code from the related question: [Google maps API getting infowindow on click with geojson file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51334153/google-maps-api-getting-infowindow-on-click-with-geojson-file), it works (but a slight adjustment to the pixelOffset of the InfoWindow makes it better).

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/fdj8cm9n/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**working code snippet:**

```js
var ufomap;

function initMap() {
  ufomap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mymap'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: 37.0902,
      lng: -95.7129
    }
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  // ufomap.data.loadGeoJson('json.geojson');
  ufomap.data.addGeoJson(geoJson);
  ufomap.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    // Location, Date-Time, and Details
    let location = event.feature.getProperty('Location');
    let datetime = event.feature.getProperty('Date-Time');
    let details = event.feature.getProperty('Details');
    let html = location + "<br>" + datetime + "<br>" + details;
    infowindow.setContent(html); // show the html variable in the infowindow
    infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    infowindow.setOptions({
      pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -42)
    }); // move the infowindow up 42 pixels to the top of the default marker icon
    infowindow.open(ufomap);
  });
}
var geoJson = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "Location": "Greensburg, PA",
        "Date-Time": "1969-01-01T10:00:00",
        "Shape": "Circle",
        "Details": "Possible contact with Visitor as a child When I was 2 to 4 years old",
        "Latitude": "40.33569572",
        "Longitude": "-79.55026848"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-79.550268,
          40.335696
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "Location": "Smithtown, PA",
        "Date-Time": "1979-01-01T10:00:00",
        "Shape": "Square",
        "Details": "Bright lights flashing",
        "Latitude": "44.33569572",
        "Longitude": "-78.55026848"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-78.550268,
          44.335696
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

```css
#mymap {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="mymap"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```